# .htaccess not rewriting my url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have made a simple url shortener. I'm trying to get .htaccess to rewrite a url that look slike this `http://chrismepham.com/q4IT612` to this `http://chrismepham.com/index.php?code=q4IT612` so that it can be used in a function that will redirect to an external url.

Here is the .htaccess code I am using:

```
SetEnv TZ Europe/London
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1
```

At the top of my index page i have the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])){
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        redirect($code);
        die();
    }
```

Heres the redirect function :

```
function redirect($code){
//test the connection
    try{
        //connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("host;dbname=dbname","user", "pass");

    //if there is an error catch it here
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        //display the error
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(code_exists($code)){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url FROM url_shortener WHERE code=?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $code);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $url = $row['url'];
        }
        header('Location: ' .$url);
    }
}
```

Why is it not rewriting the url?

Thanks

Comment: Does going to: `http://chrismepham.com/index.php?code=q4IT612` work? Are you sure it's not an issue with your PHP?

Comment: what version of apache?  Are .htaccess files enabled?  Any errors in the apache logs?

Comment: @Jon strangely that doesn't but these do http://chrismepham.com/index.php?code=YntJL4 and http://chrismepham.com/index.php?code=YHcpaO

Comment: @Jon that url is invalid, sorry my bad, must have done a crappy copy paste job during testing, codes are 6 digits long.

Comment: Try putting a slash in front of index.php on your RewriteRule.

Comment: @kmoser that worked thanks, feel free to write an answer which I'll accept!

Comment: @crm I've added an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your rule needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1
```

That makes the leading slash optional; different versions of Apache handle that differently

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule needs a slash in front of index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?code=$1
```